# Stabilizer subgroup of complex special orthogonal group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, quadratic-forms

Assume we are given a complex vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ with a non-degenerate quadratic form $q$ (which is of course unique up to isomorphism).

If we take an element $v \in V$ such that $q(v) \neq 0$, then $W=v^\perp \subset V$ is an $n-1$-dimensional complex vector space and $q$ restricts to a non-degenerate quadratic form. The subgroup $Fix(v) \subset SO(V)$ is naturally isomorphic to $SO(W)$ in this case.

I am wondering what happens in the case that $q(v)=0$. I would like to better understand the (isomorphism type) of the (Lie) group $Fix(v) \subset SO(V)$.

Since any two complex quadratic forms are isomorphic over the complex numbers, after choosing a basis we know that $Fix(v)$ will be isomorphic to the group of special orthogonal transformations of a complex vector space $Z$ of dimension $n-1$ with a quadratic form with a one-dimensional radical. I.e. $Z$ has a basis $e_1, \dots, e_{n-1}$ and the quadratic form $q$ is of the form $q= x_2^2 + x_3^2 + \dots + x_{n-1}^2$.

Ultimately, I would like to understand the difference between $SO(W)$ from the first case and $SO(Z)$ from the second case. Are these Lie subgroups somehow related? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: If $q(v) = 0$, then $q$ induces a non-degenerate quadratic form on $\langle v \rangle^\perp / \langle v \rangle$, which is a space of dimension $n-2$. So roughly speaking I think you should get a semidirect product of $SO_{n-2}$ together with some unipotent matrices that act trivially on $\langle v \rangle$ and $\langle v \rangle^\perp / \langle v \rangle$.

Comment: @spin Thank you for you comment! I agree that $Fix(v)$ acts on $\langle v \rangle^{\perp}/\langle v \rangle$ so that we get a surjective homomorphism $\phi \colon Fix(v) \twoheadrightarrow SO(n-2)$ which admits a splitting $SO(n-2) \hookrightarrow Fix(v)$. Are you aware of a more precise description of the kernel of $\phi$? Does this problem become easier when one passes to Lie algebras?